# Why an incomplete type is detected in clang inside a template method?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, smart-pointers

Today, I encountered a compile issue in clang that surprised me. I guess is reasonable but I like to dig deeper and hear more details. Some standard references if possible also.

I have a class with a template method which rely on a member which his type is undefined in the header (but not in the source). Something like the following:

```
// Menu.h
class Page;

class Menu
{
public:
    .... // stuff

template<class Visitor>
void VisitWidget( Visitor&& visitor);

private:
std::unique_ptr<Page> m_page; // destructor implemented in source file, so Page is an incomplete type
};

template<class Visitor>
inline void Menu::VisitWidget( Visitor&& visitor);
{
    m_page->Visit( std::forward<Visitor>(visitor) );
}
```

In VisualStudio, it compiles. I expect this to only complain when instanciating; so inlining. However, in clang, this doesn't compile as soon as someone includes  the header. Forcing me to include Page.h in Menu.h (which I want to avoid at all cost).

Like:

```
// Another.cpp (not Menu.cpp)
#include "Menu.h" // this trigger and error due Page is an incomplete type
```

even if the whole Another.cpp is not using VisitWidget (even in other headers)

I guess that this is caused by inline somehow, since the compiler is not obligated to really use it, but since there are templates in the middle I am not so sure. Is really clang checking the type?

Comment: @chris, see my answer. It is well-known bug in MSVC.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this compiles in MSVC because it has a well-known bug. It doesn't implement two-step template instantiation.

To elaborate. MSVC wrongly defers template parsing until it is actually instantiated in the code. Likely it happens after full `Page` definition becomes visible.

However, standard demands that the template is pre-parsed at the point of definition, and all types which are not dependent on template arguments are resolved. This fails, since `m_page` is not dependent on visitor argument - and it is still incomplete type at this point.

**P.S.** I can't even express how outraged I am at MSFT for this blatant Standard violation (among others). It makes cross-platform development a real pain, when MS-compliant code has to be ported to conforming compilers.

Comment: I'd rather call it "deficiency" instead of "bug" because afaik MSVC never claimed to implement two-phase lookup.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, we can juggle words as much as we want. But I call a blatant violation of clearly prescribed Standard rule a bug. I can even add (on the pain of being shamed) that I am personally not a huge fan of two-step instantiation itself. I understand the rationale and everything, but it often makes life of the programmer harder. But if it is in Standard, you have to implement it!

Comment: Pixelchemist -- they don't have to "claim" they implement it. Just saying they offer C++ implies they do it correctly. Clearly, it's a bug.

Comment: @mrunion: I'd agree if they'd claim to offer a 100% fully conformant c++ implementation. They don't. Hobbyists might not get into detail and sooner or later stumble across certain problems like this. Professionals should be up to date with respect to standard compliance of the compilers they have in productive use.

Comment: I'm actually inclined to think this is ill-formed NDR under the "hypothetical instantiation" rule in [temp.res]/8.

Comment: @T.C., never thought about it in such way. This is certainly an interesting view.

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you for you explanation. Do you have more information about two-step template instantiation? Thank you

Comment: @dmayola, if you want full glory details, just google it up. There is no shortage of articles on the matter.

Comment: sorry, I meant a reference to standardization article